# MongoDB Install: 'php.h' file not found #include <php.h>

Tags: php, mongodb, macos, apache

I am trying to configure the Apache server on Mac OS Catalina using PHP and MongoDB as the database. I have PHP 7.3.11 Installed.

My httpd file has this line commented out:

```
LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
```

When I run the MongoDB install I get the following message at the top of the console:

```
grep: /usr/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
```

followed but the following error at the end:

```
/private/tmp/pear/install/mongodb/php_phongo.c:22:10: fatal error: 'php.h' file not found
#include <php.h>
```

I've checked the directory listed in the first message and it contains the file php.h but there is no 'zend' directory.

I've trawled every single instance of this error message on Stack and elsewhere but can't solve the problem

Comment: Which documentation are you following?

Comment: Official docs https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/php#installation

Answer (score 0):

This error is generated if PHP's build system can't find PHP's headers. All external PHP extensions, such as the mongodb extension, or others such as xdebug, require PHP's headers to be present when compiling them.

macOS does not provide PHP headers.

Because macOS does not provide them, many people use homebrew's brew to install PHP, it's dependent libraries, and then use homebrew's "pecl" version to install the mongodb driver.

So, you need to do the following steps:

1. Install PHP and its development headers with homebrew deataily explained [here](https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-catalina-apache-multiple-php-versions)
2. Install the MongoDB PHP extension with "pecl install mongodb" (as you already did), making sure you use the homebrew version of pecl, and not macOS's default version.[following this](https://www.php.net/manual/tr/mongodb.installation.pecl.php)